# do sed to delete only if exist variable

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have this expression:

```
// Initially variables set to "" before process

HOSTS_APACHE=""

HOSTS=""

// Some process ...

export HOSTS_CANAL_TMP=$(echo $HOSTS | sed "s/$HOSTS_APACHE//")
```

It works well when apache hosts exists in a group of hosts (after processing). But it doesn't work when I have a group of hosts (`$HOSTS`) and I don't have any apache host to exclude.

So I need a similar expression to do SED of `$HOSTS_APACHE` in case there are apaches in `$HOSTS` and don't do anything in case there aren't.

Now the error when there aren't `$HOSTS_APACHE` to exclude in `$HOSTS`

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

Comment: Use an `if` statement to test whether there's anything in `$HOSTS_APACHE`.

Comment: This looks like a bad idea. What is a typical content of `$HOSTS` and `HOSTS_APACHE`? (because of the plural, I fear the worse). Besides, your command is equivalent to the parameter expansion: `export HOSTS_CANAL_TMP="${HOSTS/$HOSTS_APACHE/}"` (which doesn't suffer from the problem you're having), unless you have some regex in `$HOSTS_APACHE`. Could you explain what you're trying to achieve (you know, ProblemXY) instead of asking about a way you think is going to solve your original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** If I gather OP correctly, the issue -- or perhaps a secondary issue -- is that HOSTS_APACHE is an *unordered*, space-separated list of hosts or host names. In that case the solution is thus:

```
if [ -n "$HOSTS_APACHE" ]; then
    HOSTS_CANAL_TMP=$(echo $HOSTS | sed "s/${HOSTS_APACHE// /\\|}//g")
else
    HOSTS_CANAL_TMP=$HOSTS
fi
```

Explanation:

If `HOSTS_APACHE` is `"bar baz"` then `${HOSTS_APACHE// /\\|}` will be `"baz\|bar"`. The variable expansion using the double `//` is a global replacement of " " (space character) with `\|`.

**Old post:**

There's more than one way to accomplish this:

```
HOSTS_CANAL_TMP=$(echo $HOSTS |
    if [ -n "$HOSTS_APACHE" ]; then
        sed "s/$HOSTS_APACHE//"
    else
        cat # pass through
    fi)
```

`[ -n STRING ]` returns 0 if `STRING` has a **n**on-zero length.

The reason `|if ...; fi` works is because the if structure acts as a miniature program that receives STDIN and writes to STDOUT. Which program it invokes to process I/O is chosen by the `if` clause.

Alternatively, you could use the if-then-else structure outside the subshell:

```
if [ -n "$HOSTS_APACHE" ]; then
    HOSTS_CANAL_TMP=$(echo $HOSTS | sed "s/$HOSTS_APACHE//")
else
    HOSTS_CANAL_TMP=$HOSTS
fi
```

Comment: I have four hosts, two of them are apache. if the order is not the same as in apache variable, apache host are not deleted from the list of hosts

HOSTS_APACHE="bcd def"

HOSTS="abc bcd cde def"

if [ -n "$HOSTS_APACHE" ]; then
    export HOSTS_CANAL_TMP=$(echo $HOSTS | sed "s/$HOSTS_APACHE//")
else
    export HOSTS_CANAL_TMP=$HOSTS
fi

Comment: @user3228279 I'm still having problems understanding what you mean.

Comment: I have two variables ($HOSTS and $HOSTS_APACHE). All values in $HOSTS_APACHE are included in $HOSTS. I want a new variable named HOSTS_CANAL_TMP with all values excluding those which are in $HOSTS_APACHE.

When:
HOSTS_APACHE="bcd cde"
HOSTS="abc bcd cde def"

Then:
HOSTS_CANAL_TMP="abc def"

When:
HOSTS_APACHE="bcd def"
HOSTS="abc bcd cde def"

Then:
HOSTS_CANAL_TMP="abc bcd cde def"

Comment: @user3228279 Then my guess was correct. I updated my answer and it should solve that issue.

Comment: Yes, but I realize there is a problem. It only works in the first exemple, whem the list of apache host is consecutive and organized the same way HOSTS. In the second exemple I want to exclude "bcd" and "def" but they appear in HOSTS_CANAL_TMP because apache hosts in HOSTS_APACHE are disorganized

Comment: @user3228279 My updated answer will work if HOSTS_APACHE is out of order.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need `sed` here at all.

```
export HOSTS_CANAL_TMP=${HOSTS//"$HOSTS_APACHE"/}
```

The `${var//str/subst}` syntax is Bash-specific (but so is putting `export` before an assignment, so I'm guessing that's safe here).

However, the entire problem statement looks like you should be using an array instead.

```
HOSTS=(foo bar baz)
HOSTS_CANAL_TMP=("${HOSTS[@]/#$HOSTS_APACHE}")
```

The double quotes are for safety, but will result in an empty element in `HOSTS_CANAL_TMP`.  If you know the values in `HOSTS` can safely be used without quotes, you can fix that by taking out the double quotes.