# From bash to ksh

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

Is there any tutorial to know how to translate code from bash to ksh? How can I write this line of code in korn?

```
export TYPE_CANAL=$(echo $TYPE | sed "s/${TYPE_APACHE// /\\|}//g")
```

LAST EDITED:

Explanation of line code:

If TYPE_APACHE is "abc bcd" then ${TYPE_APACHE// /\|} will be "abc\|bcd". The variable expansion using the double // is a global replacement of " " (space character) with \|

I have two variables ($TYPE and $TYPE_APACHE). All values in $TYPE_APACHE are included in $TYPE. 
I want a new variable named TYPE_CANAL_TMP with all values excluding those which are in $TYPE_APACHE.

Comment: I do not know KornShell. But KornShell is compatible with Bash, did you change the #!Shebang?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761744/do-sed-to-delete-only-if-exist-variable

Comment: @johnnyevolunium `ksh` and Bash are not mutually compatible.  There are Bash-only features which are not available in `ksh` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Your command doesn't quote `$TYPE` properly so it will squish any whitespace into individual spaces.  Is that intentional?  I'm assuming not, and changing that part of the code as well.

The command will take any space in `$TYPE_APACHE` and replace it with `\\|`, then pass that to `sed` as the regular expression for strings to remove.  That can be done portably with

```
TYPE_CANAL=$(echo "$TYPE" | sed "s/$(echo "$TYPE_APACHE" | sed 's/ /\\|/')//g")
export TYPE_CANAL
```

In Bash, this could be done a lot more elegantly with arrays, which are supported in `ksh` as well, but without a proper description of the problem this code is supposed to solve, there are too many places we'd have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Next time please post example input and output. I think you want the following:

```
TYPE="a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6"
TYPE_APACHE="a2 a4 a5"

TYPE_CANAL_RAW=""
for type in ${TYPE}; do
   echo ${type}
   if [[ ${TYPE_APACHE} != *${type}* ]]; then
      TYPE_CANAL_RAW="${TYPE_CANAL_RAW} ${type}"
   fi
done
TYPE_CANAL=${TYPE_CANAL_RAW# }
```

I think you should make a function from the code above and not try
to avoid a for-loop.
When you really need to change it, you must make the sed string look like

```
echo ${TYPE} | sed -e 's/a2//' -e 's/a4//' -e 's/a5//' -e 's/  */ /g'
```

Be aware of special characters in TYPE_ARCHIVE when you try to use sed.